# How to make it hard for users to download video in html5?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture

I would like to know what are the best practices while streaming a video in html5. I know you can't prevent people downloading video, but I just want to know the ways to make it harder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DRM protection to encrypt the video if this is the approach you want to take.

DRM is controversial (see Firefox discussion at link below) but it is being baked into the standards with HTML5 EME (Encrypted Meida Extensions) so is becoming more mainstream. EME essentially allow a browser request a trusted (by the video producer) element in the browser/device to decode and play an encrypted video. See a good overview of EME at the second link below.

- https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2015/05/12/update-on-digital-rights-management-and-firefox/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

This approach may also allow you support a download and go use case - i.e. people will be able to view your video offline.